# Signalling an error from a parser rule in PLY

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, lexer, ply

I'm using [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) to parse commands for a custom definition file. Commands are defined one per line, and each one should start with a reserved keyword followed by a number of strings. I have successfully managed to write a lexer and parser for the grammar, but I am having problems raising a `SyntaxError` from within a production.

According to [PLY's documentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn35), this is possible simply by throwing a `SyntaxError` from within the body of a parser rule:

> If necessary, a production rule can manually force the parser to enter error recovery. This is done by raising the SyntaxError exception like this:
>
> ```
> def p_production(p):
>     'production : some production ...'
>     raise SyntaxError
> ```

My code raises a `SyntaxError` within a production when it encounters invalid syntax, but when I run the program this error is not raised. Here is a minimal working example:

```
from ply import lex, yacc

class Parser(object):
    # reserved keyword tokens
    reserved = {
        "r": "R"
    }

    # top level tokens
    tokens = [
        'CHUNK',
        'NEWLINE'
    ]

    # add reserved tokens
    tokens += reserved.values()

    # ignore spaces and tabs
    t_ignore = ' \t'

    def __init__(self):
        # lexer and parser handlers
        self.lexer = lex.lex(module=self)
        self.parser = yacc.yacc(module=self)

    def parse(self, text):
        # pass text to yacc
        self.parser.parse(text, lexer=self.lexer)

    # detect new lines
    def t_newline(self, t):
        r'\n+'
        # generate newline token
        t.type = "NEWLINE"
        return t

    def t_CHUNK(self, t):
        r'[a-zA-Z0-9_=.:]+'
        # check if chunk is a keyword
        t.type = self.reserved.get(t.value.lower(), 'CHUNK')
        return t

    def t_error(self, t):
        raise SyntaxError("token error")

    def p_instruction_list(self, p):
        '''instruction_list : instruction
                            | instruction_list instruction'''
        pass

    # match instruction on their own lines
    def p_instruction(self, p):
        '''instruction : command NEWLINE
                       | NEWLINE'''
        pass

    def p_command(self, p):
        '''command : R CHUNK CHUNK CHUNK CHUNK'''
        # parse command
        if p[2] not in ["a", "b"]:
            raise SyntaxError("invalid thing")

    def p_error(self, p):
        raise SyntaxError("parsing error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = Parser()
    parser.parse("""
    r a text text text
    r c text text text
    r b text text text
    """)
```

The above example runs without outputting anything, which means it has successfully parsed the text, even though a syntax error should be raised in `p_command` due to the line `r c text text text` (the second token `c` is invalid; only `a` or `b` would be valid).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are responsible for printing error messages, and you don't:

> One important aspect of manually setting an error is that the `p_error()` function will **NOT** be called in this case. If you need to issue an error message, make sure you do it in the production that raises `SyntaxError`.

I don't believe `p_error()` should raise `SyntaxError`. It should just print an appropriate message (or otherwise register the fact that an error occurred) and let error recovery proceed. But in any event, it is not being called in this case, as indicated by the above quote.

I'm not 100% convinced by having the lexer raise `SyntaxError` either. My preferred strategy for lexical errors is to just pass them through to the parser and thereby centralise error handling in one place.

If you don't care about error recovery, don't use an `error` token in any rule. That token is only used for error recovery. If you just want to throw an exception as soon as an error is encountered, do that in `p_error`, and call `p_error` explicitly in places where it will not be called automatically (such as token errors and errors detected in semantic actions). You could throw `ValueError` or something derived from it; I'd stay away from `SyntaxError`, which has particular meaning to Ply and to Python in general.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that `SyntaxError` is special, and you cannot simply throw a `SyntaxError` and expect it to eventually stop execution. Enabling `debug=1` in the `__init__` call to the parser helped me to see this problem: when my custom `SyntaxError` is thrown, an `error` token is added to the stack, and it doesn't find a rule that accepts it, and so it is discarded silently. I tried adding a rule that accepts the syntax error but this led to an infinite loop, so I instead just resorted to throwing custom exceptions that weren't descended from `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Can you share example code of how to handle `error` tokens in the parser? I have trouble with infinite loops when I try to make `instruction_list` accept `error` tokens.

Comment: instruction_list is not a natural place to detect errors, because it has no resynchronization token. I'd put the error rule in instruction, by adding the production `instruction: error NEWLINE`. That will resynchronize at the new NEWLINE character. I don't know how you got infinite loops unless it was by throwing SyntaxError when you shouldn't. On the whole, if you have some code which does not function as expected and you want help with it, you should try to write a specific question *with a [mcve]* and specific symptoms. "I had trouble" and "it didn't work" are not adequate problem reports.

Comment: I added the production you specified, by taking my example above and adding a new rule: `def p_error_handler` which uses the production `instruction : error NEWLINE`. In the method body it raises `p[1]`. It doesn't throw the error, even if the rule is above `p_instruction`. It does, however, appear to work if I make the production `instruction : error` (i.e. no `NEWLINE`). Is it important to have `NEWLINE`? For the record, I don't care about recovering after an error is encountered.